# How to set the principal in the current scenario

Tags: c#, wpf

Consider the following code, the goal is to set the System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal
and retrieve it in another window.... simple code with comments to clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

```
        Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() =>
        {
            // do in another task so that the UI does not freeze
            var user = modelLogin.Login(username, password);

            // run on the current dispatcher thread to show results of login
            currentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                if (user == null)
                {
                    errorText = "Authentication failed";
                }
                else
                {
                    // set the principal
                    // how ever setting the value here, does not really set it on the main thread
                    // what i mean by this is that when the login window close i want to get 
                    // the  principal i set here in another window
                    // but it does not seem to work that way
                    // how to propely set this value in this current situation?
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = authentication;
                }

                ToggleIsBusy();
                CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
            }));
        }));
```

Any ideas what how I can do it ?

Comment: `currentDispatcher` points to UI dispatcher or background thread dispatcher?

Comment: in the constructor of the window is set :

            this.currentDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

So it's the UI Dispatcher I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting CurrentPrincipal of Thread, ***set it for all Thread by setting it on AppDomain which will set it for all threads including Main thread***:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(authentication);
```